# Create test for service

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This service create new players and add them to list.

```
@Service
public class PlayerService {

@Autowired
private List<Player> playersList;
@Autowired
private Game game;


public void createPlayers(int players) {
    for(int i = 1; i < players; i++) {
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setPlayerName(i);
        playersList.add(player);
    }
    game.setPlayersList(playersList);
}
}
```

And I tried to write a test for this service. But it doesn't work. Any ideas whats wrong?

```
@InjectMocks
private PlayerService playerService;
@Mock
private Game game;

@Test
public void addPlayer() {
    playerService.createPlayers(1);
    assertEquals(1, game.getPlayersList().size());
}
```

Comment: By adding List<Player> to a bean you expect Spring to fetch all beans of type Person. If you want to have a list of players, then create bean List<Player> or a class that holds players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by many you should prefer Constructor Injection instead of Field Injection. See for Example this [post on reflectoring.io](https://reflectoring.io/constructor-injection/)

The resulting Code is far easier to test:

```
@Service
public class PlayerService {

    private List<Player> playersList;
    private Game game;

    public PlayerService(List<Player> playersList, Game game) {
        this.playersList = playersList;
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void createPlayers(int players) {
        for(int i = 1; i < players; i++) {
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setPlayerName(i);
            playersList.add(player);
        }
        game.setPlayersList(playersList);
    }
}
```

And your Testcode:

```
@Test
public void addPlayer() {
    var playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    var game = new Game(...);
    var playerService = new PlayerService(playerList, game);
    playerService.createPlayers(1);

    assertEquals(1, game.getPlayersList().size());
}
```

As you can see you can test your PlayerService with plain UnitTest. No need of any Mocking-Framework.

---

BTW. it would be nice if you could tell us what is not working. What is the unexpected behaviour? What are the Exceptions. This would make it far easier to give proper answers :)

> But it doesn't work. Any ideas whats wrong?